# Keras - NN prediction of error in metrological measurement.

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I have example data which contain coordinates of points on the x-y plane (for 
example 2.0000 , 4.0000), next using monte carlo method, a small random error 
is added to those coordinates to simulate a set of points measured by a 
metrological machine.

This may sound trivial, but Im not really sure what to do next with this data, Im trying to build a model which predicts the error in measurement, but I have problem in visualizing the whole concept, ie. should the input layer of the network have neurons which receive real coordinates of the points and 
simulated coordinates, or simulated ones only? Or maybe I should estimate 
measurement error for each simulated point and and use it with coordinates of 
those points in the input layer? Also, how many neurons the network should 
have on the output layer and how should I interpret that data? I know this 
probably isnt the best description of the problem, but I am a complete 
begginner in this field, so any theoretical help or practical examples will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not even sure if this is possible except the points are always integers in which case you can do this without neural networks. But, nonetheless, here are the answers to your question:

You should put the simulated coordinates only to the input of the model.

The output should have 2 neurons, 1 will output the estimated error of dimension `x`, and the other of dimension `y`.

The process of training is as following: you put the simulated points to the network input layer, let the network predict the error for `x` and `y` axis and then you compare the predicted results with the real (correct) ones. If the predicted ones are correct, you move on to the next sample (pair of coordinates) and if they are not the same, you update weights with backpropagation and SGD. You repeat this process for desired number of epochs, depending on your data (fine-tune number of epochs so it's not too low and not too high).

I hope this clears up things for you :)